# How to use a variable from c# class in a html parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, url-parameters

Im trying to get something to work for a school project.

I have the following html-code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptStreams" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="conainer">
        </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="content-1 marginRight" >
                <div><h1><%# Eval("Name") %></h1></div>
                <div class="content-1-image"> 
                <a href="Streambrowser.aspx/?game=League of Legends"><img src="http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-140x196.jpg" alt="League of Legends" style="width:140px; height:196px;" </a></div>
                <div class="content-1-viewers" > 
                <div>Viewers:<h1><%# Eval("Viewercount") %></h1></div>
                </div>
                 <!---content-1-image ends here-->

            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate>
      </div>
  </FooterTemplate>

   </asp:Repeater>
```

and the following asp class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Twitch.tv
{
    public partial class Gamebrowser : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<Game> Games = new List<Game>();
        Query db = new Query();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            Games = db.ReturnAllGames();

            rptStreams.DataSource = Games;
            rptStreams.DataBind();

        }


        protected void ImageButton1_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem im having is trying to get the paramater in the repeater to work.
I want it to get the gamename from the gamebrowser.aspx.cs list and put it in the parameter from the html-file. This way every link put in the repeater will have the right parameter and will link to the right page.

So something like this:

```
 <a href="Streambrowser.aspx/?game=(Gamename from list right here!)
"><img src="http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-140x196.jpg" alt="League of Legends" style="width:140px; height:196px;" </a></div>
```

I hope i have been clear enough but, its a bit hard for me to explain, ask me any questions u want :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does your Query come from? What namespace does it use? Btw, your image tag is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

just use Eval instead of link: `<%# Eval("href") %>`
and in your query form your link: `concat('http://your.link/link.aspx?game=', gamename_field) as href)`

Comment: Thankyou for the fast response, im gonna try it later this day, ill let u know if it worked